# change row to column with array in C

Tags: c, arrays

In the ouput I have array data like this

( 1) ( 2) ( 3) ( 4) ( 5) 
( 6) ( 7) ( 8) ( 9) (10)

I want to change that output with new ouput like this

( 1) ( 6) 
( 2) ( 7) 
( 3) ( 8) 
( 4) ( 9) 
( 5) ( 10)

what should i do?

this is my code to display the first output

```
void generateRandomData(char **data){
int i, j, max;
srand(time(NULL));
for(i=0;i<JUMLAHDATA;i++) {
    max=rand()%(10)+1;
    data[i]=malloc(max+1); 
    for (j= 0;j<max;j++) {
        data[i][j]=rand()%(24)+97;
    }
    data[i][j] = '\0';  
}

}

void swapData(char *x,char *y){
   char temp;
   temp = *x;
   *x = *y;
   *y = temp;
}

void selectionSort(char **data){
    int i, j, min;
    for (i=0;i<JUMLAHDATA-1;i++){
    min=i;
        for (j=i+1;j<JUMLAHDATA;j++){
            if (strcmp(data[j],data[min])<0){         
            min = j;
            }        
        }
        swapData(data[i],data[min]); 
   }
}

void cetakData(char **data){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<JUMLAHDATA;i++){
        printf("(%2i) ",i+1, data[i]);
        if((i+1)%5==0) printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: So you want to transform a 2D array sized [n][m] to [m][n] ? Because you're code doesn't match that .

Comment: How is your array defined?  Is it a regular 1D array, or a 2D array?  Is it just the print order that has to be changed?

Comment: sorry i forgot to put the code

Comment: i was changed the code....please take a look

Comment: `printf("(%2i) ",i+1, data[i]);` doesn't do what you appear to think it does.

Comment: If it is just about _printing_, you don't need to swap. Just print differently.

Comment: Please (re)read the guidelines on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  The `swapData()` and `selectionSort()` functions are extraneous (non-minimal), and `main()` is missing (incomplete).  It is possible to deduce some of what you want from what you show, but the printing `cetakData()` doesn't print the randomly generated strings.  The `5` that appears in your code is not clearly related to `JUMLAHDATA` (you don't show that definition, either).  Clean parameterization of functions is an art form; you'd do better passing size arguments to the functions.

Answer (score 1):

First get your data arrays/pointers straight :)

```
void cetakData_by_twos(int *data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < JUMLAHDATA / 2; i++) {
        printf("(%2i) (%2i)\n", data[i], data[i + JUMLAHDATA / 2]);
    }
}
```